# JMeter - Test Fragment option to change or insert Controller

Tags: jmeter

Test Fragment has options using Right Click to Change Controller and Insert Parent which seems wrong, Is it a bug or is there a special use case for it?

Especially because Logic Controllers aren't allowed (using GUI) to be under Thread Group. Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's indeed a bug, you reported it under:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61713

It has been fixed for upcoming version following 3.3:

- http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?rev=1814066&view=rev

Comment: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61713 Is the fix to override createPopupMenu() similar to thread group?